# Fileupload copying file to 2. directory

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a file_upload of images, where I want the script to add the image to one folder called: foto,
AND then I wan't it to copy the same image to: foto_ikon.

How can I do this?

I think I have to use the copy() but I don't know how to, really.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"../foto/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

This is how my move_uploaded_file looks like.

It works perfectly.

I've tried to do it like this:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"../foto/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
copy($_FILES["file"]["name"], "../foto_ikon/");
```

But it's not the right way, I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you've performed `move_uploaded_file` there is no file at `$_FILES["file"]["name"]` anymore (that is why actually function is named **move**`_uploaded_file`)(and as [DaveRandom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/889949/daverandom) mentioned - there was no file ever).

So if you need to copy it - do that using its **real current location** (the place you've moved the original file to) `"../foto/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]` like this:

```
copy("../foto/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"], "../foto_ikon/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Comment: +1, although there *never was* a file at `$_FILES["file"]["name"]` ;-)

Comment: You misinterpreted my friend, he was copying the files['name'] not TMP from what he thought was the foto folder. Thats all!

Answer (score 1):

Simple, you moved the file from TMP to "../foto/", copy it from there, not from your current directory:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"../foto/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
copy("../foto/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"], "../foto_ikon/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```